# localStorage.setItem not working in IE10 on XPages

Tags: javascript, local-storage, xpages, lotus-domino, internet-explorer-10

Ok, this is a weird one.

I've got a Domino 8.5.3FP3 with UP1 installed and regardless what I try on that server - localStoraget.setItem doesn't work in IE10!

I've got an empty database with an empty XPage inside it and I use the console to issue: 
    localStorage.setItem("test","ok")

This works in IE8 & IE9 on that same server, but not on IE10. (Using IE10 to emulate IE9 or IE8 doesn't work)

On Domino 8.5.3 & IE10 I get the error message: "Function expected"

Using my local dev machine (Domino 9) the same database works.

(IE10 localStorage works on any other page, like google.com for instance).

I've compared the source AND HTTP headers using Fiddler and the only difference I can find is that Domino 8.5.3 uses lowercase for **utf-8**, where as Domino 9 will output: **UTF-8**

You can view the comparison here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9681254/question/comparingDominoVersions.png

Ideas?

Thanks!

/J

Comment: What version of Windows do you use ?

Comment: I found another site with utf-8 all in lowercase. But it worked there as well, but they didn't use Dojo. So I don't know how useful that test was. Thought it worth mentioning anyway..

Comment: Aren't there anyone out there with a Domino 8.5.X server that has IE10 installed that could give it a shot? Just open the IE Developer Toolbar (F12), in the console - enter: localStorage.setItem("test", "ok") and run! Please post back the results..

Answer (score 1):

Check if this might solve your problem 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx